# Blog Overflow database error

Tags: bug, blog-overflow

[blogoverflow.com](http://blogoverflow.com/), which is linked from site-specific blogs, says

> ## Error establishing a database connection

I believe this is an error.

Comment: I hope they [have a backup](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/12/international-backup-awareness-day.html).